# Is $argc interchangeable with count($argv)?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Are there any functional differences I need to make note of? I would assume `$argc` would be a bit faster since it's a pre-counted value already in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's splitting hairs, but yes, `$argc` is a few nanoseconds faster. (Remember the file name is an argument too.)